# Calculate value_counts for multiple independent columns grouped within a set of other grouping variables efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to calculate count (such as presented by value_counts) for values across a large number of indepedent columns grouped by a fixed set of 2-5 other columns. This exercise is as part of a data mining in data with upto millions of rows and upto 50-100 columns. Hence the solution needs to be as efficient as it can be. In order to pull all this data in memory together, I upfront converted all the columns to type 'category' while reading the source data.

following data can be used as example:

```
raw_data = {'grpVar1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
        'grpVar2': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Z','X'], 
        'catVar1': ['car', 'bike', 'car', 'bike', 'car', 'bike'], 
        'catVar2': ['red','blue','black', 'red','blue','black']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['grpVar1', 'grpVar2', 'catVar1', 'catVar2'])
df = df.astype('category')
```

For the above data I expect to get summarize data as follows. Please ignore the sort order of the groups.

```
grpVar1  grpVar2  Column   Value    Count
A        X        catVar1  car        2
         Y        catVar1  bike       1
B        X        catVar1  bike       1
         Y        catVar1  bike       1
         Z        catVar1  car        1
A        X        catVar2  black      1
                  catVar2  red        1
         Y        catVar2  blue       1
B        X        catVar2  black      1
         Y        catVar2  red        1
         Z        catVar2  blue       1
```

One option i can think of is to melt the dataframe then do value count. But it doesn't seem to be a smart choice memory wise (as now the data is no longer categorical and uncompressed) and performance wise. Please advise.

Comment: You can melt and then do a pivot_table operation.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through columns you want to melt. Do groupby and concatenate. This might save some space. Speaking of time, this might not beat the melt function.

```
df['cnt'] = 1
output = []
for col in df.columns[2:-1]:
    grp = df[list(df.columns[:2])+ [col] + ['cnt']].groupby(list(df.columns[:2])+ [col]).sum().dropna()
    grp['column'] = col
    grp.rename({col: 'value'}, inplace=True)
    output.append(grp)

output = pd.concat(output)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to stay away from column by column processing due to poor performance.Perhaps I can pool columns together for melt. This will alleviate memory problem with melting all columns together.

Comment: @Vineet Yes try melt, it will be fast. And you might try multiprocessing if your computation need is very intensive. :)